# Is the laptop using the integrated or discrete graphics?

Tags: laptop, graphics-card, integrated-graphics

I've bought a new laptop with discrete graphics (a Radeon mobility card), but I know there's also integrated graphics somewhere inside...

The laptop came with no OS installed, so I had to install the OS and drivers by myself.

Is there a way to know if it uses the discrete graphics or the integrated graphics?

UPDATE:
I'm using Win7 64bit. Does the laptop brand\model matter? I would like a way to find out what graphics solution is being used on *any* laptop...

Comment: that brand and model of laptop do you have?

Comment: How do you "know"?

Comment: We need more details. Try using speccy http://www.piriform.com/speccy

Comment: What OS did you install?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start --> Run --> `dxdiag`.

The display tab should tell you your current graphics driver. Also, there's usually a BIOS option to set either integrated or discrete graphics or sometimes a hybrid/let the OS choose option.